# Is there a way in Swift to partially match a generic?

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, nsview

That is, if I have a class C that takes two generics A and B, is there a way where I can cast an object to C where I don't care what B is?

My specific use case is that I need to bridge between NSView functionality and the new SwiftUI in a multi-window, but non-document based application. The problem I am having is, given an NSView, I need to obtain the SwiftUI View that it is managing (in my case a View called `ContentView`).

Note that I do have a solution, which I include below, but it involves the use of `Mirror` based reflection and I am wondering if there is a better way, most likely involving the use of `as?` to cast to a partial match of a generic.

The bridging is done using the NSHostingView hence it should seem that one would just do the following:

```
if let hostingView = NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.contentView as? NSHostingView<ContentView> {
    // do what I need with 'hostingView.rootView'
}
```

Unfortunately, NSHostingView.rootView does not return the actual `ContentView` that I created, it returns a modified version of that view dependant on the modifiers used. (In my case I'm using `.environmentObject` modifier.) As a result the `if` statement above never returns true because the type is not `NSHostingView<ContentView>` but rather `NSHostingView<ModifiedContent<ContentView, _bunch_Of_Gobbletygook_Representing_The_Modifiers>>`. One way to "solve" the problem is to print out the result of `type(of: hostingView)` when I create the window, and then change my cast to include the current version of the "gobbledygook", but that is brittle for the following two reasons:

1. If I change the modifiers, the compiler will not warn me that I need to update the cast, and
2. Since the "gobbledygook" contains single underscored values, I must assume those are internal details that could change. Hence without my changing any code, an OS update could cause the cast to start failing.

So I have created a solution in the form of the following NSView extension:

```
extension NSView {
    func originalRootView<RootView: View>() -> RootView? {
        if let hostingView = self as? NSHostingView<RootView> {
            return hostingView.rootView
        }
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        if let rootView = mirror.descendant("_rootView") {
            let mirror2 = Mirror(reflecting: rootView)
            if let content = mirror2.descendant("content") as? RootView {
                return content
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This allows me to handle my needs using the following:

```
private func currentContentView() -> ContentView? {
    return NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.contentView?.originalRootView()
}

... sometime later ...

if let contentView = currentContentView() {
    // do what I need with contentView
}
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to implement `originalRootView` without the use of reflection, presumably by allowing a partially specified cast to the `ModifiedContent` object. For example, something like the following (which does not compile):

```
extension NSView {
    func originalRootView<RootView: View>() -> RootView? {
        if let hostingView = self as? NSHostingView<RootView> {
            return hostingView.rootView
        }
        if let hostingView = self as? NSHostingView<ModifiedContent<RootView, ANY>> {
            return hostingView.rootView.content
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

The problem is what to put for "ANY". I would think some form of `Any` or `AnyObject`, but the complier complains about that. Essentially I would like to tell the compiler that I don't care what ANY is so long as the ModifiedContent has RootView as its content type.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Just curious why do you need to go from a NSView to the corresponding SwiftUI view? What do you plan to do with it after you get it?

Comment: Actually `originalRootView` is senseless, because in SwiftUI view is struct, so even if it would work it would return **a copy** of root view, because it is a value, so modifying it there will have no effect on view kept in `NSHostingView`.

Comment: In my case I’m using it to enable/disable items in the menu based on the state of the data that is tied to the specific window. (For example the ‘Clear Log’ menu item is disabled if there is nothing in the log displayed in the window.) So you are correct about the copy, but I’m using it to read state, not change it. Perhaps instead of returning the view I should return the state instead? In any event, I am interested in more SwiftUI based alternatives, but it does seem that macOS is still a bit of a “second class citizen” in this new API.

Comment: However @Asperi makes a good point. Just because my solution works does not mean it is the correct way to do it. I will take another look at other ways to do this, perhaps via a combination of bindings in the menu and Combine for getting the views to react.

Comment: That said, I think my original question is still a fair one, but it looks like the answer may be no, at least not in Swift 5.1.

Comment: It looks like the answer to my question is indeed "no" there is no way to partially match a generic as of Swift 5.1. Perhaps it will be in a future version. As for my use case, I have managed to use Combine to reduce the need for my `originalRootView`. I still need it, but only for updating the enable/disable status of menu items that are dependant on separate windows. All my other uses of it I have managed to replace with Combine based messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make the results official, the answer is "no" there is no way to partially match a generic as of Swift 5.1.